# PS4 glitchy on startup

Tags: ps4

About 2 weeks ago my Playstatiom 4 started being glitchy where when I turn it on the start up screen comes up but has grey lines every few inches that come in and out for about a minute and then it either starts normally on its own or I have to power it off and restart. Any ideas why this is happening or anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Check storage space, unplug any extra devices, lower your display settings.

Answer (score 1):

I would rule out that it isn't a TV or HDMI cable problem first, I had a similar issue with an old HDMI cable once.

Try it in a different HDMI port first, and if it still does it, try another cable. If that's the problem at least your PS4 is OK!